# How do I generate warning for an unused variable in Perl?

Tags: perl, variables, warnings, unused-variables

How do I generate warning for an unused variable in Perl ?

```
my $var1 = 0;
my $var2 = 10;
printf("%d",$var2);
```

Should generate warning that `$var1` is unused

**EDIT**
I tried `perlcritic` on my script.It gave me several of each of these warnings:
What does each of these mean ? I don't see any unused variable warning anyway.

```
#Bareword file handle opened at line 98, column 9.  See pages 202,204 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
#Loop iterator is not lexical at line 1068, column 5.  See page 108 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
#Subroutine prototypes used at line 553, column 1.  See page 194 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
#Two-argument "open" used at line 1072, column 5.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)
```

Comment: Do you already know about perlcritic, the Perl static analysis tool? You can configure it to emit such warnings.

Comment: I don't. I will try those.

Comment: I misinterpreted the possibilities perlcritic offered, and posted a comprehensive comment on that as an “answer”. It also shortly explains the perlcritic warnings shown above.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look to the [warnings::unused](http://search.cpan.org/~gfuji/warnings-unused-0.06/lib/warnings/unused.pm) perl module, it's designed for that purpose.

You can also use `perlcritic` like amon said in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

On the topic of using `perlcritic` to detect this:

I misinterpreted the [`ProhibitUnusedVariables`](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl%3a%3aCritic%3a%3aPolicy%3a%3aVariables%3a%3aProhibitUnusedVariables) rule. It does not apply here, as the current implementation of that rule treats assignment as a use.

That is, it warns on `my $unused;` but not on `my $unused = 1;`.

To use `perlcritic`, you can request a severity, ranging from the default “gentle” `-5` to the “brutal” `-1`.

#### Short explanation of the warnings:

- bareword filehandles are considered outdated. Use lexical variables, like `open my $fh, ...;` and `my $line = <$fh>`.
- It can be considered a bad practice to use the default `$_` as loop variable in a `foreach`-style loop. It is usually preferable to introduce a new, lexical variable whose scope is restricted to the loop, like

  ```
  for my $pet (@pets) {
    $pet->feed($pet->favourite_treat);
  }
  ```
- Subroutine prototypes are the thing in the parens after a sub definition, as in `sub foo() { ... }`. Unless you already know what prototypes do in Perl, don't use them, and just `sub foo { ... }`.
- It is considered a good practice to perform an `open` like

  ```
  open my $fh, "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
  ```

  The error handling may be omitted if you `use autodie`. The explicit mode can avoid shell injection (consider the valid filename `rm -rf *; echo pwned |`). This is a must for modern Perl.

You may disagree with some of these rules (at least I do, in two of these cases). You can use a `.perlcriticrc` file to modify the rules to your preferences. See the [perlcritic documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/THALJEF/Perl-Critic-1.118/bin/perlcritic#CONFIGURATION)